# how make any element in foreach loop when call specific function change its content

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

how make any element in foreach loop when call specific function change its content
in view

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
{                       
.
.
.
<div class="inline-popups">
 <a class="more" href="#test-four" data-effect="mfp-3d-unfold" onclick="fun(@item.Id)">المزيد</a>
</div>
.
.
.
.
 <div class="popup-gallery arrow header1" id="hol">
   @foreach (var ite in item.ImgEvents)
   {
       <div class="gallery hvr-shutter-in-horizontal">
         <a class="titan-lb" data-titan-group="gallery" href="../../@ite.ImgPath" onclick="fun(@item.Id);"></a>
         <img src="../../@ite.ImgPath">
       </div>
    }


</div>

 <div class="views">
    <p>@item.VisitorNum</p>
    <span></span>
 </div>
  }
```

in ajax code

```
function fun (id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddView", "Home")',
        type: 'post',
        data: {Id:id},
        success: function (response,textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Problem happend during the validation, display message related to the field.

        }
    });
}
```

in controller

```
    public int AddView(int Id)
    {
       // bool res = false;
        var obj = db.Events.Find(Id);
        obj.VisitorNum++;
        db.SaveChanges();
        int num = obj.VisitorNum.Value;
        return num;
    }
```

i want when call fun() call action controller and increase VisitorNum in database
and return number in ajax to show it in specific item
i want determined who item cal function to increase its view

Comment: Did you hear of [Generic Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) is a method that is declared with [Generic Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx) is a placeholder for a specific type that a client specifies when they instantiate a variable of the generic type

Comment: no , there another solution??